# How to keep the value of a method in memory inside a class?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a method called `function1` that's stored inside a class `cls`. How do i modify the below function such that if the same value is passed through `val1`, the `returnhandle` function doesn't have to be called?

```
class cls
{
public:
    void function1(const int& val1, int& val2, int& data);
};

void cls::function1(const int& val1, int& val2, int& data)
{
   int handle;
   handle = returnhandle(val1);
   data = readhandleddata(handle, val2);
}
```

Comment: 1. Create a map of `int` -> `int` where you map `val1` values with `handle` values. 2. Store already computed values into the map. 3. If you want to compute new value, first check if it's in the map. If it is, return the value from map, if it is not, compute + add to map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the comment, create a map of results you've already computed, check if it's in there first, and if not, compute it, store it, and return it.

```
class cls
{
    std::map<int, int> data_map;
public:
    void function1(const int& val1, int& val2, int& data);
};

void cls::function1(const int& val1, int& val2, int& data)
{
   int handle;
   auto i = data_map.find(val1); 
   if (i != data_map.end()) {
        return i->second;
   }
   handle = returnhandle(val1);
   data = readhandleddata(handle, val2);
   data_map[val1] = data;
}
```

If your callback isn't slow or you don't get a lot of cache hits, this can make your program slower, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the relationship val - handle. A possible solution:

```
class cls
{
public:
    void function1(const int val1, int& val2, int& data)
    {
        if (_handles.find(val1) == _handles.end())
            _handles[val1] = returnhandle(val1);
        data = readhandleddate(_handles.at(val1), val2);
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<int,int> _handles;
};
```